# equation about the Riemann metric and integral

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$function and there exist a natural number $k$ such that 
$$ f(tx,ty,tz)=t^kf(x,y,z) $$
for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $\omega$ be the volume element on $S^2$ induced by the Riemann metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to show the following equation holds.
$$ \int_{S^2}kf\omega=\int_{D^3}\left(\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}\right)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$
where $D^3$ is the unit disk on $\mathbb{R}^3$. First I got the following equation by differentiate the above equation by $t$.
$$ \left(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)f=kf $$
Then I computed 
$$\int_{S^2}kf\omega$$
by using the Stokes' theorem and polar coordinates, but I was not able to get what I wanted. I'm still unfamiliar with differential forms, so there may be good ways. Please give me some advice.